# How to find the list of files owned by Google service account? (The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded)

Tags: python, google-drive-api

We publish the file daily to a shared folder using the Google service account. Recently, we are receiving an error, 
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&alt=json returned "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.">

We cleared the files from the Shared folder. Though the files are disappeared from the shared folder, it Looks like files are still owned by Google service account and Quota is full. I am planning to delete all the files owned by the Google service account. Is there a way, we can find the list of all files owned by the service account?

Answer (score 0):

A simple [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), while authenticated with the Service Account, should list all files in the Service Account Drive, including files that are in Trash.

A Service Account (if it has not been granted domain-wide delegation and it's not impersonating anyone) is just like a regular account, with its own `My Drive`. The difference is that you cannot access it via Drive UI.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: I have the same issue. However i m NOT uploading to the service account storage, but to another g drive account , that can be accessed by the service account. However i get the 403 error: "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded". Moreover by looking in the google drive folder, i can verify that the account has plenty of storage left.